# How many types of calling NSOperationqueue?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsoperationqueue

What are the differences among following types calling Queues,which one is the best?

A)

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

B)

```
      NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
       [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // Background work

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // Main thread work (UI usually)
    }];
   }];
```

C)Adding NSoperation which has subclassed  to NSoperationQueue for example http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

D)

```
    [[NSOperation mainQueue] addOperation:myOperation];
```

IS it right approach? because this code adds NSoperation to mainQueue.This is not good for
background task.Usually mainQueue will be used for updating UI Only.

E)If I have missed anything except above call methods for Queue , please mention them also in answer.

Answer (score 2):

None of those examples is *best*, and they're not even very different from each other. As the name implies, `NSOperationQueue` is a queue, i.e. a first in first out (FIFO) data structure, that contains operations. You can create your own operation queues, or you can use an existing one.

**Example A** is a reasonable example of using an existing queue, the main queue. You wouldn't want to put a synchronous network request on the main thread (which is what you get with `+mainQueue`) because it would block the user interface, but it's not necessarily a bad choice here because the request is asynchronous and the operation queue being passed in is used only to run the completion handler. Indeed, the completion handler might need to manipulate the user interface, and that should be done from the main queue.

**Example B** illustrates creating a new operation queue and scheduling an operation on that queue. That operation in turn schedules *another* operation on the main queue. This is a pretty typical scenario -- again, you should only manipulate the UI from the main thread, so it's common to have a background operation create an operation that runs on the main thread in order to update the UI.

**Example C** is similar to B, except that the operation in question is a subclass rather than one created from a block. `NSOperation` existed before Grand Central Dispatch and blocks came along, and it used to be that the only way to create an operation that did something interesting was to subclass `NSOperation` and override `-main`. The blog post you linked says it was posted Feb. 16, 2008, which would certainly have been from that era. Creating operations from blocks is a newer and often more concise style, but there's nothing wrong with subclassing especially if you might need to perform the same kind of operation in several places. Note also that that article uses `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, which is an easier way to run something on the main thread than creating *another* `NSOperation` subclass.

**Example D** is too vague to really comment on -- it merely shows how to add some unspecified operation to the main queue. You're right that you wouldn't want to do that for long-running operations -- those should be scheduled on a background queue instead to avoid blocking the UI. But without knowing what `myOperation` does, you can't say that it's right or wrong.

So, none of your examples are incorrect, and none is really better than another. To the extent that they're different, it's because they're used in different situations. For example, `NSURLConnection` takes an `NSOperationQueue` and a block as parameters because it needs to wait until the connection is done before it schedules an operation created from the completion block. Once the connection is done, though, `NSURLConnection` will do pretty much what you see in examples B and D.

Comment: @JeffWood You don't have to use the main queue *only* for updating the UI -- the idea is simply that you don't want to do anything that would take very long on the main thread because that would prevent the main thread from doing the important work of updating the UI and responding to user input. As for quitting... *all* your application's threads including the main thread will stop when the application quits. The main thread isn't something that transcends the application -- each app has its own collection of threads and its own main thread.

Comment: Sorry caleb, I am asking mainqueue does not work in secondary thread.even If we use mainqueue as Example 1, it means synchronous connection. Am I right? because we are not running asynchronous connetion in secondary thread.

Comment: If you're creating *synchronous* connections, you'll want to do that from a background thread. Example B is a reasonable template for that kind of thing. Example A uses the main thread, but only for running the completion handler after an asynchronous connection. Either one is a reasonable approach. The thing you should avoid is running synchronous connection on the main thread.

Comment: subclassing NSoperation as  Example C has  more advantage than using blocks as Example B.Because if
Example B will work until the view controller is deallocated in which it has been mentioned .but in example C, I can include NSURLCOnnection delegate methods as NSoperations and push them to global NSOperationQueue. AM I right? Which one is the best between example B and Example C?

Comment: That really only depends on where you create the background queue -- I don't believe that the difference you mention is due to subclassing vs. blocks, but just a matter of where the background queue is created. You could instantiate the queue in your app delegate, for example, and it would be available for the life of the app. You can create operations of either type in your delegate methods, but of course the delegate methods can't *be* operations. Anyway, you might want to consider `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection` -- it's a newer API and IMO much easier to use.

Comment: you are great as u have answered with tolerance.. :)